# Matlab manually finding histograms and pdfs of images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

Image processing using Otsu's method and getting histogram and PDF for white/black pictures. Here's the code which I wrote but I couldn't get the PDF via the histogram.

```
I = imread('sample.jpg');
level = graythresh(I);
X = rgb2gray(I);
A = im2bw(X,level);
A2 = im2bw(X,58/255);
B = medfilt2(A2);
figure, imshow(I)
figure, imhist(X)
figure, imshow(A)
figure, imshow(A2)
figure, imshow(B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imhist` only shows the histogram, not the PDF. If you're looking for the PDF of X, you can use:

```
histogram( X(:), 'Normalization', 'probability' );
axis tight
```

EDIT: Full code

```
I = imread('sample.jpg');
level = graythresh(I);
X = rgb2gray(I);
A = im2bw(X,level);
A2 = im2bw(X,58/255);
B = medfilt2(A2);
figure, imshow(I)
figure; histogram( X(:), 'Normalization', 'probability' );
axis tight;
figure, imshow(A)
figure, imshow(A2)
figure, imshow(B)
```